# At what stage can I access Session in Servlet?

Tags: session, servlets

I have a servlet. In my `doPost` method, I am trying to set some attributes in `Session`.
`session = req.getSession(false)` is resulting in session value being `null`. So, am not able to set anything in it. At what stage of my `servlet` will I be able to access `session` and store some attributes in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing like stage to create session in a `HttpServlet`. You can create it any time once a Servlet gets initialized and before response gets committed.

From [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28boolean%29), There are two methods to create `HttpSession`.

`getSession()`  -- Returns the current session associated with this request, or if the request does not have a session, creates one.

and `getSession(boolean create)` -- Returns the current `HttpSession` associated with this request or, if there is no current session and create is true, returns a new session.

Here you are passing false in `getSession(false)`. So, If session doesn't exist, It will return `NULL`.

When creating a Session first time  Use `getSession()` or `getSession(true)` and set attributes then for subsequent use access it using `getSession(false)` and get attributes.